# How to elegantly make a custom assertion error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I made a bunch of functions that control a message-based instrument. I know how to use them but the functions should be fool-proof in case somebody else wants to code with it after I'm gone. Here is an example function:

```
def AutoRange(self, Function, Source, Value):
    """Enable or disable the instrument autoranging feature.\n
    :Function: "source" or "measure".
    :Source: "v" or "i".
    :Value: 0 or 1."""

    # <Something goes here to check if the inputs are valid>
    self.WRITE("smua.%s.autorange%s = %s" %(Function, Source, Value))
```

To comply with the input requirements I initially added a `RaiseException` at the start in an ugly way:

```
    AllowedFunctions = ("source", "measure")
    AllowedSources = ("v", "i")
    AllowedValues = (0, 1)
    if not(Function in AllowedFunctions and Source in AllowedSources and Value in AllowedValues):
        raise Exception("/!\ Error in Keithley.Autorange(): Input not allowed.")
```

After reading about `assert()` I replaced the `if` with this:

```
    MyErrorMessage = "/!\ Error in Keithley.Autorange(): Input not allowed."
    assert (Function in ("source", "measure")), MyErrorMessage
    assert (Source in ("v", "i")), MyErrorMessage
    assert (Value in (0, 1)), MyErrorMessage
```

A possible neater variant would be this:

```
    ValidInputs = (    Function in ("source", "measure")
                   and Source in ("v", "i")
                   and Value in (0, 1))

    assert (ValidInputs), "/!\ Error in Keithley.Autorange(): Input not allowed."
```

The second option is nicer now that I think of it because then I can tell specifically which input was invalid. So my question is: **is this how you should handle assertions? 1** `assert()` **for 1 input? If not, what is the adviced structure?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: `assert` is not intended for such use, to quote the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement): "Assert statements are a convenient way to insert **debugging** assertions into a program" - you can get Python to easily ignore all assertions with `-O` parameter. Just validate your inputs the old fashion way (you can use a validation map to save on verbosity) and raise appropriate exceptions when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do what Python does?

Let's see an example:

```
open("foo", "q")
# => ValueError: invalid mode: 'q'
```

`open` is in C, but you can see how it looks like for e.g [`gzip.open`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/lzma.py#L289):

```
if "t" in mode:
    if "b" in mode:
        raise ValueError("Invalid mode: %r" % (mode,))
```

Don't be scared of making the code a little longer; you can't really avoid it in Python. And also, "Error in Keithley.Autorange(): Input not allowed." doesn't tell the programmer which input is not allowed. In this case, explicit and clear is better than clever and short.

I'd do:

```
def auto_range(self, function, source, value):
    if function not in ["source", "measure"]:
        raise ValueError("Invalid function: %s" % function)
    if source not in ["v", "i"]:
        raise ValueError("Invalid source: %s" % source)
    if value not in [0, 1]:
        raise ValueError("Invalid value: %d" % value)
    # ...
```

Not directly relevant to your questions, but it is best to stick to the language's coding style: in Python, variables are in `snake_case` (lowercase with underscores).

Comment: Yes, thank you. just before seeing your reply I made an edit about how I should really tell which input was invalid instead of sending a general error that is not indicative enough.

Comment: In our case I am not sure to see the difference between an assertion error and a custom raised error actually, except that `assert()` is a bit more compact than `if not - raise`?

Comment: There are at least two that come to mind: consistency, and the fact noted by @zwer that assert-checks can be disabled to speed up a production system. The point I'm making is, what's good enough for Python should be good enough for Guimoute :) And Python does not value compactness. You want compact, go learn J or something (sample: `quicksort=: (($:@(<#[), (=#[), $:@(>#[)) ({~ ?@#)) ^: (1<#)`)

Comment: Also, take a look at what Python manual says about `ValueError`: "Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as `IndexError`." That's pretty much your use case, no?

Comment: I could see someone use True/False instead of 0/1 here so the type is probably not even guaranteed. I understand your point about compactness but what's annoying here is that a one-line function becomes 7 lines because of the "safety" layer we add.

Comment: Then set as appropriate. I was halfway to making that line `if not 0 <= x <= 1:` just to make a point. If it was meant to be a boolean, I wouldn't even validate it, just see if it's truthy, really. All that beside the point: Python code is full of functions where _documentation string_ is several times bigger than the code. It truly does not matter.

Comment: `if source not in ["v", "i"]:` could be `if source not in "vi":` (okay, maybe more confusing)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yup. And I left it as `["v", "i"]` exactly for that reason (self-documenting).

Comment: well, I know you know :)

Comment: @Amadan: So "size doesn't matter". I will keep that in mind, thanks. Maybe I can separate the code in 2 parts so my potential readers (who are worse than me at Python) can clearly tell the difference between `# Input validity check` and `# Actual function performed by the instrument`.

Comment: If you separate them, you lose the self-documenting factor. I'd keep it in, and if you expect your readers to be that illiterate, comment to the effect of `# Validation of inputs` and `# Calculation` should suffice. Then again, this is getting quite subjective.

Comment: That is what I meant, not really "separate" them but have two paragraphs with a title comment.

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry, I should have understood that :P But yeah, this is a very common pattern, where you put "guards" on the top of the function, then proceed with the real stuff if all the guards are satisfied.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre careful with your suggestion because that makes "vi" a valid input that does not raise errors while only "v" and "i" are supported.

Comment: @Guimoute that's a very valid point. Who needs `vi` in 2018 ? :)